# Finding the elements using parent in Selenium

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-ide

```
<div>
    <span>First line</span>
    <p>Second line</p>
    <span>Third line</span>
    <p>Fourth line</p>
</div>
```

My requirement is to get to the div and find elements which are the child of the div tag.

If I use css selector as div>p:nth(0) and div>p:nth(1), I will get my 1st and 2nd p tags respectively, the same can be applied for the span also.

But is there a keyword or a way that can be applied after reaching div tag and say (0) which will get my 1st span tag, (1) which will get my 1st p tag, say (2) which will get my 2nd span tag, (3) which will get my 2nd p tag.

I don't where there is a way through css locator or xpath locator to achieve this. If there is a way please share it.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to achieve here? Do you want to find all of these span  and p tags inside the div with a single locator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get the child elements. You can use `nth-child()` selector to achieve this. Reach to the `div` tag and then use `nth-child()`. Following is an example. For simplicity here, I will assume your div tag has an `id="myId"`,
So to get to first `span` element, use following css selector:

```
[id='myId'] :nth-child(1)
```

or

```
div#myId :nth-child(1)
```

or

```
#myId :nth-child(1)
```

whatever suits your case.

**NOTE:** There is a space character before `:nth-child(1)`

Similarly, to get to the first `p` element:

```
div#myId :nth-child(2)
```

and to get to the second `span` element:

```
div#myId :nth-child(3)
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should try by XPath:

```
//div/*
```

this should retrieve you all the child elements.

Comment: Could you please provide an example by answering my example.

Comment: If you will use the XPath locator, with the pattern I've provided before  you will get the array of elements. you should try running this in the developer tools console: $x("//div/*") and you shall get the results as you asked

Comment: This will get you the child elements of *all* DIVs... not just the ones that contain SPAN and P, right? That doesn't seem like a good answer to the question.

Comment: you should give your div an id and then use it like //div[@id='your_id']/* otherwise you will get any div with span or p in it.

Answer (score 0):

**- First answer of your question** : You have to use List of web elements.
- Example : `List<WebElement> LstwebE = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div/*"));`

You can use all element by this way :

```
LstwebE.get(0);
LstwebE.get(1);
LstwebE.get(2);
LstwebE.get(3);
```

Result of `LstwebE.get(0);`  : `<span>First line</span>`

**Extra Notes :**
- As I understand you want to find sibling elements.

- Xpath will fulfill this requirements.
- First of all get element and apply siblings xpath :

Two type of siblings are there :

**1. preceding-sibling : For preceding element**

Take your example code and try this xpath for preceding :

```
//div/p[1]/preceding-sibling::span
```

This xpath will find first `<p>` tag and then find its preceding span tag.

Result of xpath : `<span>First line</span>`

**2. following-sibling : For following element**

Take your example code and try this xpath for following:

```
//div/p[1]//following-sibling::span
```

This xpath first find first `<p>` tag and then go for following span

Result of xpath : `<span>Third line</span>`

- ***Note : Use unique class or attribute of div element like :*** `//div[@class='xyz']/p[1]/preceding-sibling::span`

Comment: replace //div/p[1]//following-sibling::span with //div/p[1]/following-sibling::span

Comment: I think both are valid xpath. Please comment more. What is actually a problem?

Comment: Actually / is use for first level element. // is use for all child level element.